# What is the intuitive meaning of the covariant derivative on a sphere?

Tags: tensors

I get that it is used to construct covariant equations in physics. But otherwise, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the most natural directional derivative when your space might be curved and "direction" therefore becomes a bit iffy.

More specifically, the standard directional derivative along a vector $v$ at a point $p$ is
$$
\partial_v F(p)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(p+hv)-F(p)}{h}
$$
This doesn't make sense on a general manifold, as the space might not be a vector space and $p+hv$ doesn't work. Secondly, $F$ could be, say, a vector field and comparing two tangent vectors at different points is not easily done.

Covariant derivative fixes this to work with tangent vectors as direction in a consistent way, as long as we have either curvature information (through a connection) or a metric (through a Riemannian inner product structure) on our manifold.